# Email Functionality not Working in 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email, magento2.3.0

In my custom module, I have added email functionality. It's working in 2.1 and 2.2. I have updated to 2.3.0 and now it crashes.

Email send code is as below.

```
$sender = [
            'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer_name),
            'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer_email),
        ];

$to_email = $this->_helper->getSendMailTo();

$sendToInfo = [
                'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($to_email),
            ];

$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('config_email_settings_email_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($sendToInfo)
                    ->getTransport();


$transport->sendMessage();
```

I am getting exception as

> main.CRITICAL: Exception message: The input is not a valid email
>   address. Use the basic format local-part@hostname

Where email address is simple **john@gmail.com**

```
[2019-01-08 07:45:19] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: The input is not a valid email address. Use the basic format local-part@hostname
Trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\zendframework\zend-mail\src\AddressList.php(233): Zend\Mail\Address->__construct('email', 'john@gmail...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\zendframework\zend-mail\src\AddressList.php(33): Zend\Mail\AddressList->createAddress('email', 'john@gmail...')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\zendframework\zend-mail\src\AddressList.php(80): Zend\Mail\AddressList->add('email', 'john@gmail...')
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\zendframework\zend-mail\src\Message.php(518): Zend\Mail\AddressList->addMany(Array)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\zendframework\zend-mail\src\Message.php(169): Zend\Mail\Message->updateAddressList(Object(Zend\Mail\AddressList), Array, NULL, 'Zend\\Mail\\Messa...')
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Mail\Message.php(104): Zend\Mail\Message->addTo(Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\generated\code\Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor.php(102): Magento\Framework\Mail\Message->addTo(Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder.php(147): Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor->addTo(Array, '')
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\generated\code\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->addTo(Array, '')
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save.php(113): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor->addTo(Array)
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\generated\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor.php(24): Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save->execute()
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(108): Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\generated\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor.php(39): Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#16 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(159): Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Order\Save\Interceptor))
#18 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#26 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#28 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#29 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#30 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Can anyone give solution please for this?

Comment: Hi, did you setup cron job?

Comment: I have not set cron job. it's in local. I'm sending mail from controller.

Comment: Did you try with static email address? See same exception occur or not.

Comment: Yes I have tried with static email address. Same exception as above.

Comment: Can you paste complete code?

$sendToInfo = "can you paste here valid email address"

Comment: post whole code for easier debugging

Comment: is working now ?

Comment: I have used  $sendToInfo = [
                'email' => 'john@gmail.com',
                'name' => 'John'
            ];
but still not working. same issue.

Comment: did you change the $sender as well? because probably the error was generated by the **_escaper**

Comment: Yes I have changed it to. Please check log error in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I have Found Solution and Now it's Working

```
$sender = [    
           'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer_email),
           'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer_name)
         ];

$to_email = $this->_helper->getSendMailTo();

$transport= $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('config_email_settings_email_template')
        ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
        ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
        ->setFrom($sender)
        ->addTo($to_email, 'Name')
        ->getTransport();

$transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: Thank you this helped alot. I ran into the same issue the problem is the version of magento. In Magento 2.4, you can pass the array, in magento 2.3 you need to pass name and email separately.

Answer (score 3):

Please replace your code with following code and check after clear your cache, also please remove **"_escaper"** from your code.

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('config_email_settings_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($variables)
            ->setFrom($emailSender)
            ->addTo($emailRecipient)
            ->setReplyTo($replyToEmail, $replyToName)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: @Magecode does this work for you?

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: I'm getting eoor on this line ->addTo($sendToInfo)

Comment: I have passed email ID static in $sendToInfo = [
                    'email' => 'magecode@example.com'
                ];

Comment: Add like this : $senderInfo = [
            'name' => 'Mage Code',
            'email' => 'magecode@example.com''
        ];

Comment: @Magecode Please check my edited and and try as per edited ans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87991/discussion-between-magecode-and-aasim-goriya).

Comment: @Magecode Please check my updated code, I have just checked and its working fine for me in Magento 2.3 version, so please check and let me know if any issue.

Comment: It's also not working.

Answer (score 2):

Since Magento 2.3, Magento uses Zend Framework 2 for sending emails. Which probably changed the logic used for parsing array with the recipient data.

---

So here are few variants on how you can properly send email in Magento 2.3:

1. For multiple recipients: use array where key is the recipient's email address and value - recipient's name (*note, the same rules applied to sender details*):

```
$sender = [$this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer_email) => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer_name)];

$to_email = $this->_helper->getSendMailTo();

$sendToInfo = [$this->_escaper->escapeHtml($to_email) => 'Recipient Name'];

$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('config_email_settings_email_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($sendToInfo)
                    ->getTransport();


$transport->sendMessage();
```

2. Or you can use the code below to send an email to a single recipient. This code is backward compatible with Magento 2.2 and lower versions:

```
$to_email = $this->_helper->getSendMailTo();

$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('config_email_settings_email_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom($this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer_email))
                    ->addTo($this->_escaper->escapeHtml($to_email))
                    ->getTransport();


$transport->sendMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Contact is vendor and Us is module.Here i am posting my form data to my frontend controller Post.php

step 1: Create email_templates.xml in app/code/Contact/Us/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template id="send_email_email_template" label="Email Form" file="email_template.html" type="text" module="Contact_Us" area="frontend"/>
```

step 2: Create email_template.html in app/code/Contact/Us/view/frontend/email

```
<!--@subject xMage-support@-->
   <!--@vars {
     "var data.comment":"xMage-support",
     "var data.email":"support@xmagestore.com",
     "var data.name":"XMageStore"
    } @-->


  {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

  {{trans "Dear %name" name=$data.name}}
  {{trans "we received your request regarding %queryregarding" 
    queryregarding=$data.requestType}}

  {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Step 3: Create Post.php controller in app/code/Contact/Us/Controller/Post

```
<?php
namespace Contact\Us\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
 */
protected $inlineTranslation;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
protected $_escaper;
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}

/**
 * Post user question
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    if (!$post) {
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return;
    }

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
    try {
        $recipientMail = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('email');

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($post);

        $error = false;

        $sender = [
            'name' => 'xMageStore',
            'email' => 'support@xmagestore.com',
        ];

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($recipientMail)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('Thanks for contacting us. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
        );
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addError(
            __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.' . $e->getMessage())
        );
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return;
    }
  }
}
```