# Magento 2 Invalid email format

Tags: magento2.3, order-email

How to solve this ?

> 03 17:24:57] main.CRITICAL: Invalid email format
>   {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(code:
>   0): Invalid email format at
>   /home/xyz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:710)"}
>   []

***here is my order_new.html***

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Your Order : %increment_id confirmation" increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description"
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>.' store_email=$store_email |raw}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(1) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1 style="font-size: 17px;">Customer Email: <span class="no-link">{{var order.getCustomerEmail()|escape|nl2br}}</span></h1>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                        <p>{{trans "%email," email=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                        <p>{{trans "%email," email=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Customer Comment"}}</h3>                        
                        <p>{{trans "%comment," comment=$order.getOscOrderComment()}}</p>
                    </td>                    
                    <td class="address-details">

                    </td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: share your email template in your question for which you are facing issues.

Comment: @Sumit i just overrride order_new.html,i add my template above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check di.xml file of your custom modules, maybe your custom module class is overriding the core email functionality `Magento\Framework\Mail\Message`.

Check this core class in your files.

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: after update this code which commands i have to run ?

Comment: You need to run php bin/magento s:s:d and php bin/magento cache:flush from the root of the website.

Comment: i updated your code but not working,before it was working suddenly this problem occurs

Comment: would you please this also - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287493/magento-2-the-input-is-not-a-valid-email-address-use-the-basic-format-local-p

Comment: I think the issue is with the additional variables you've used in this email template which are causing issue. You can debug it by removing them once and try again.

Comment: Have you upgraded your Magento?

Comment: yes you are right i upgraded code but after upgrade it is working.

Comment: now i also replace my custom template with default template.
mail is coming but mail subject is showing and email is blank

Comment: Check this once https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256369/email-functionality-not-working-in-2-3-0

Comment: Also, remove header and footer section from the template and try again. I've faced same kind of issue on my website as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98260/discussion-between-sumeet-bajaj-and-sumit).

Comment: yes i override this and when comment that code now mail is working thanks man for your valuable time